# installing Apache POI for android using a linux pc

Tags: android, linux, apache-poi

I'm developing apps for android, using eclipse, on a linux(ubuntu) pc. I cannot find any information on how to install Apache POI. could someone please explain step by step how to install Apache POI onto a linux computer?

Every tutorial i could find about installing Apache POI the person is using either mac or windows, no linux version. so i tried this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7sOhyxRQ5Y of someone installing Apache POI on a mac. I downloaded the Apache POI tar.gz, extracted it. then just like they did in the video, i went to properties, clicked "add JARs", added the jar, then the jar file showed up in the "referenced libraries" folder, just like in their example, so far so good. but now they opened up one of the classes just to show what it looks like, when i open up the class it doesn't show java code like theirs did, it shows an error "source not found" and "jar file has no source attachment. what did i miss?

Comment: If you want the source code, you'll need to download the `-src` package as well, and then when Eclipse says `source not found` point it at the expanded src download. (The `-bin` one contains the POI jars and their dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

Promoting a comment to an answer

On the [Apache POI Download Page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html), you will find two sets of files, the *Binary Distribution* and *Source Distribution*. From what you've written, you've got the Binary one, but also need the source one too

In the Binary Distribution, you'll find all of the Apache POI [jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), and the JavaDocs. In the Source Distribution, you'll find the source code, the unit test source code, the test files used by the unit tests, and the javadocs. (If you want to make changes to Apache POI, the source package has everything you need to rebuild it)

From what you've said you're after, you'll want to download the binary packages, and add the appropriate POI Jars and the dependencies - see the [components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) to work out what jars and dependencies are needed based on which parts of Apache POI you want to use. Then, download the sources package, expand, and tell Eclipse that's where it can find the source for the POI jars. At that point, you'll be able to see the code of POI in Eclipse, debug / step into it etc